# Why multiple initialising of .dll from cuda

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-2019, conv-neural-network

I'm enjoing reading all throug the github. But now I got a problem to be solved I didn't find yet.

I'm running

- Visual Studio 2019 on
- Win 10 64 bit
- python 3.7 64-bit
- Tensorflow 2.3.0 on GPU only
- CUDA V10.1.243 with CUDNN
- GPU: GTX-1080Ti

I do training for convolutional networks.
While running, I noticed something: The initializing happens twice. I don't think it is meant to do so and I hope this is the root of another problem I have which I won't mention here. Step by step.

So how do I initialize the CUDA just once? Here the Info:

```
2020-08-05 13:16:07.603055: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.323190: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.347449: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 28 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 451.17GiB/s
2020-08-05 13:16:10.347743: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.352223: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.356249: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.357740: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.362188: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.364747: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.373196: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.374251: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 13:16:10.374928: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-05 13:16:10.383795: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1d28de782a0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 13:16:10.383987: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-05 13:16:10.384768: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 28 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 451.17GiB/s
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385117: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385334: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385595: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385758: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.385930: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.386211: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:10.386962: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 13:16:11.005566: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-05 13:16:11.005721: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-08-05 13:16:11.005810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-08-05 13:16:11.006873: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8678 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-08-05 13:16:11.011234: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1d2b7583c70 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 13:16:11.011462: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512, 512, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 512, 64)      36928     
=================================================================
Total params: 37,568
Trainable params: 37,568
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
2020-08-05 13:16:13.133969: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 13:16:13.883702: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
2020-08-05 13:16:13.920654: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll

1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 7.8599 - accuracy: 9.1553e-05
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 280ms/step - loss: 7.8599 - accuracy: 9.1553e-05 - val_loss: 7.7643 - val_accuracy: 8.7738e-05
========================> END:  05.08.2020-13:16:14
Der Thread 'MainThread' (0x1) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
Das Programm "python.exe" wurde mit Code 0 (0x0) beendet.
```

As you can see the .dll data is initialized multiple time.

The code i used was:
main.py

```
from model import *
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np
import datetime


ascent = scipy.misc.ascent()
ascent = np.reshape(ascent,ascent.shape+(1,))
ascent = np.reshape(ascent,(1,)+ascent.shape)

mask = np.zeros(ascent.shape)
mask[0:10,50:150]=1
model = unet(input_size = (512,512,1))


history = model.fit(ascent, mask, steps_per_epoch=1,epochs=1, validation_data = (ascent, mask), validation_steps =1)
print('========================> END: ', datetime.datetime.n
```

and model.py

```
import numpy as np 
import os
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as trans
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *

def unet(input_size,pretrained_weights = None):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv2)
    
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
                                        #1e-4
    model.summary()

    return model
```

Do you have any idea what I can do about that?

Best regards!

---

### EDIT:

I've tried to run the code with python -v like AKX mentioned.
As a result I get a huge log. It's too big to post here. But still here is a link to the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m8vav1tnewhp41p/issueCUDAinitialize.txt?dl=0

The Part where the CUDA is loading is the following:

```
...
# C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\utils\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\utils\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\DGrollmisch\\.conda\\envs\\KI-Project\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\keras\\utils\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'tensorflow.keras.utils' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C4AB0DEC8>
# C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\wrappers\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\wrappers\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\DGrollmisch\\.conda\\envs\\KI-Project\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\keras\\wrappers\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
# C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\DGrollmisch\\.conda\\envs\\KI-Project\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\keras\\wrappers\\scikit_learn\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C4AB11B48>
import 'tensorflow.keras.wrappers' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C4AB11708>
import 'tensorflow.keras' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C4AACE848>
import 'tensorflow' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C430F65C8>
import 'model' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C2926FF88>
# destroy tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer
# C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\__pycache__\base_layer_v1.cpython-37.pyc matches C:\Users\DGrollmisch\.conda\envs\KI-Project\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_v1.py
# code object from 'C:\\Users\\DGrollmisch\\.conda\\envs\\KI-Project\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\keras\\engine\\__pycache__\\base_layer_v1.cpython-37.pyc'
import 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0000013C4AB15088>
# destroy tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer_v1
# destroy tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib
2020-08-05 14:45:26.141350: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.161125: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 28 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 451.17GiB/s
2020-08-05 14:45:26.161413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.167517: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.171373: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.172995: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.177250: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.179778: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.188220: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.188956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 14:45:26.189772: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-05 14:45:26.199148: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x13c49ff9c00 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 14:45:26.199384: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-05 14:45:26.200115: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:02:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.582GHz coreCount: 28 deviceMemorySize: 11.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 451.17GiB/s
2020-08-05 14:45:26.200572: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.200937: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.201175: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.201358: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.201550: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.201815: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.202166: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 14:45:26.202942: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 14:45:26.815334: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-05 14:45:26.815493: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-08-05 14:45:26.815590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-08-05 14:45:26.816590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8678 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-08-05 14:45:26.819910: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x13c67f4f600 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 14:45:26.820091: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
# destroy tensorflow.python.framework.constant_op
# destroy tensorflow.python.distribute.distribution_strategy_context
# destroy tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training
# destroy tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training_v1
Model: "functional_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512, 512, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 512, 512, 64)      640       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 512, 512, 64)      36928     
=================================================================
Total params: 37,568
Trainable params: 37,568
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
# destroy tensorflow.python.autograph.core.ag_ctx
# destroy tensorflow.python.autograph.core.ag_ctx
# destroy tensorflow.python.autograph.impl.api
# destroy tensorflow.python.framework.ops
# destroy tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_spec
...
```

Here the requirements.txt with the installed packages in my environemnt:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
astor==0.8.1
astropy==4.0.1.post1
astunparse==1.6.3
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.2.0
bleach==3.1.5
cachetools==4.1.0
certifi==2020.4.5.2
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.6.0
entrypoints==0.3
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.17.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.29.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
imageio==2.8.0
importlib-metadata==1.6.1
install==1.3.3
ipykernel==5.3.0
ipython==7.15.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.17.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter-client==6.1.3
jupyter-core==4.6.3
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
kiwisolver==1.2.0
libtiff==0.4.2
Markdown==3.2.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.2
memory-profiler==0.57.0
mistune==0.8.4
more-itertools==8.4.0
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==5.0.7
networkx==2.4
noise==1.2.2
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
opensimplex==0.3
opt-einsum==3.2.1
packaging==20.4
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==7.1.2
pip==20.2.1
pluggy==0.13.1
prometheus-client==0.8.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
protobuf==3.12.2
psutil==5.7.2
py==1.8.2
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
Pygments==2.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyrsistent==0.16.0
pytest==5.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyWavelets==1.1.1
pywin32==227
pywinpty==0.5.7
PyYAML==5.3.1
pyzmq==18.1.1
regions==0.4
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.6
scikit-image==0.17.2
scipy==1.4.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
setuptools==47.3.1
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0
tensorflow-gpu-estimator==2.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
tifffile==2020.6.3
tornado==6.0.4
traitlets==4.3.3
urllib3==1.25.9
wcwidth==0.2.4
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wheel==0.34.2
wincertstore==0.2
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

Comment: Try running with `python -v` to turn verbose import logging on. Hopefully the multiple initialization log messages get interspersed with import log messages, to help you pinpoint if/where a stray import causes the double initialization.

Comment: That log doesn't look quite correct, since those `#destroy`s should come at the end of your program. I suppose there's buffering happening. Anyway, can you please  tell us more about the  "another problem I have which you won't mention here"? This may be entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've done editing to the original question regarding your suggestion.

The other problem is a RAM consumption problem.
I'm feeding a standard UNet with one single 1104x1104x1 tiff image. The result is, that it uses my 11GB Ram on the GPU to run. So Batches of multiple Images are impossible. Don't know whether this is related to this problem.

Comment: I have installed CUDA, CuDNN, Visual Studio 2019 and all the stuff on another computer(different hardware setup). Same problem there. So it wouldn't be a hardware issue. Still, I get the double initialization, which I wonder where it comes from.